# Запуск приложения на iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

При запуске приложения на 5s iphone вылазит такая ошибка.

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
>
> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

Перед этим для подключение google maps sdk, был сменен Bundle identifier, именно по это причине выскакивает эта ошибка.

Comment: Удаление старой версии приложения с устройства и чистая пересборка (после Clean) не помогает?

Comment: Ваш профайл создан под другой  Bundle identifier, Вам необходимо создать новый профайл.